# Book (or series) where magic users clasp hands with the catalyst and say "Catalyst give me life"

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book or series, don't know which it is, that my kid picked off the shelf randomly at the library a few years ago but doesn't remember the title.

Magic and science both exist. I think aliens were invading and Merlin was instrumental in stopping them? (Unsure on that part) I distinctly remember that the magic system has two parts, those who can actually cast magic and 'catalysts', people who can't use magic but enable others to refill their magical energy. The magic user clasps hands with the catalyst and says "Catalyst, give me life" which allows the magic user to refill their energy.

I remember there was also something about multiple timelines and jumping between them, Astral projection and hiding in 'time folds, and other weird mixes of science and magic.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169386/book-about-mages-who-can-harvest-magical-energy-from-the-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Three related trilogies by [Robin Hobb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hobb), starting with _[Assassin's Apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Apprentice)_, involve a magic-using character described as a "catalyst".

Answer (score 6):

The catalysts make me think that this could be [the Darksword trilogy](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/DST/the-darksword-trilogy). The Merlin character could be either Saryon or Simkin. Merilon is also the name of the empire. The aliens are a ruthless race called the Hch'Nyv. There is a mix of science and magic, but I don't remember anything about timelines. Disclaimer: it's been almost two decades since I've read the books.

Comment: possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205659/old-book-about-a-land-surrounded-by-a-thick-fog-wall-where-people-are-exiled-to/205684#205684